# Get println! to prefix given string with current time

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
println!("Start") // Start
printlnt!("Start"); // [231209_14:00:00] Start
```

How could I make a macro like the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a macro as below

```
macro_rules! printlnt {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {
        println!("[{}] {}", chrono::Local::now().format("%y%m%d_%H:%M:%S"), $($arg)*);
    };
}
```

Comment: Although you should probably use logging or tracing instead.

Comment: Note that this won't work with formatted messages, e.g. `printlnt!("foo = {}", foo);`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d2d13e650d0095fb5f780bccd11e2976)

Comment: @Jmb You can do `println!("[{}] {}", chrono::Local::now().format("%y%m%d_%H:%M:%S"), format_args!($($arg)*));` then it works.